# OpenCL_result not the same as that in the example-Julia

Tags: opencllink

My system is "Windows-x86-64", `Mathematica` version is 10.0, my card is GTX860M

- When I'm trying this example, my result is not the same like that in the example.

  example/AutomaticSingleToDoublePrecisionConversion

Is this just a 'zoom' problem?

[image]

  *

Comment: What example are you trying?

Comment: I don't think it is a zoom problem as the DataRange is defined to be {{-2.0, 2.0}, {-2.0, 2.0}}. It works fine for me on a Mac in 10.0.0.1. Have you copied the example code into a notebook and started from a fresh kernel?

Comment: I get the same problem. There is also an error: "OpenCLLink experienced an internal error." This is on Windows 7 with an Nvidia GTX 550Ti graphics card. The compilation goes okay so I suspect a driver bug or perhaps the GPU's double precision support isn't up to scratch.